# How do I draw beizer curve on SpriteKit using Swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to figure how to draw a bezier curve. I'm building a Kite flying game and the Kite string needs to be a beizer curve.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: @FabianLauer if you'd ever used a 2D game engine you'd realise that one of the expectations many users have is that it can draw. SpriteKit is an anomaly because it has horrible drawing, so it hides it. Worse, it's not capable of doing rapid, performant changes to a bezier curve, so obfuscates away from discussion about 2D drawing in all its documents. Typical Apple, it's omissions inform more than its claims. Therefore this is, more than likely, a valid query from a person at the end of their rope. If you'll excuse the pun.

Comment: @Confused I commented on this question because it seems to me like the user asks SO to Google for him. And it seems to me like I made more of an effort than Mit Sengupta because I googled and came up with half a dozen promising links in under a minute.

Comment: @FabianLauer Yet you first suggested he was seeking code written, not lessons in googling. And you haven't tried any of your links... nor realised there is no performant solution. This is, if you knew the framework, more than just a passing curiosity, it's a genuine problem of the framework, which isn't mentioned anywhere but the link in my "answer".

Comment: Alright, enough already. -_-

Answer (score 2):

[`SKShapeNode`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skshapenode) takes in bezier lines, and other lines, but you have to articulate those lines somewhere else, somehow else, in the frameworks of Apple or yourself, and create CGPaths for it.

And you can't dynamically adjust the passed CGPath, you have to replace it for every single change.

This only serves to compound enormous problems with the performance of SKShapeNode. Which is woeful.

Read here for more info on its uselessness: http://sartak.org/2014/03/skshapenode-you-are-dead-to-me.html

Unfortunately, there is no good answer to your question.

Comment: Thank you very much! Very much appreciated! :)

Comment: I found this solution https://cocoapods.org/pods/BezierCurveView . What is your take on this ?

Comment: This will be even slower. It uses drawRect(), which is a horror story for speed. And it's using UILayers which don't play well with SpriteKit. Since you're not yet a SpriteKit user, I'd suggest finding an engine that's drawing friendly and using that.